# Why does python random generate the same result?

Tags: python, function, random, pygame

I wrote a rather simple program in Python. Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import time
from math import *
from random import *
from pygame.locals import *




def mutateBrain(brain):
    a = 0
    for element in brain:
        brain[a][0] = element[0] + (1 * (0.5 - random()))
        brain[a][1] = element[1] + (1 * (0.5 - random()))
        a = a + 1
    return brain;


def generateFirstBrain():
    genbrain = []
    h = 0;
    while randint(0,5) != 0:
        asd = [2 * random(), 2 * random()]
        genbrain.insert(h, asd)
        h = h + 1
    return genbrain

pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))



screen.fill(pygame.Color(255,255,255))

pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),(310,0,30,30))
movesa = generateFirstBrain()
movesb = generateFirstBrain()
movesc = generateFirstBrain()

cola = (255,255,0)
colb = (255,0,255)
colc = (0,255,255)


while 1:

    movesa = mutateBrain(movesa)
    movesb = mutateBrain(movesb)
    movesc = mutateBrain(movesc)

    step = 0
    acurrentx = 320
    acurrenty = 240

    bcurrentx = 320
    bcurrenty = 240

    ccurrentx = 320
    ccurrenty = 240

    totalsn = 0



    if (len(movesa) >= len(movesb)) and (len(movesa) >= len(movesc)):
        totalsn = len(movesa)
    elif (len(movesb) >= len(movesa)) and (len(movesb) >= len(movesc)):
        totalsn = len(movesb)
    else:
        totalsn = len(movesc)

    for g in range(totalsn):
        screen.fill(pygame.Color(255,255,255))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0),(305,0,30,30))

        try:
            acurrentx = acurrentx + 1 - movesa[step][0]
            acurrenty = acurrenty + 1 - movesa[step][1]
        except IndexError:
            acurrentx = acurrentx


        try:
            bcurrentx = bcurrentx + 1 - movesb[step][0]
            bcurrenty = bcurrenty + 1 - movesb[step][1]
        except IndexError:
            bcurrentx = bcurrentx

        try:
            ccurrentx = ccurrentx + 1 - movesc[step][0]
            ccurrenty = ccurrenty + 1 - movesc[step][1]
        except IndexError:
            ccurrentx = ccurrentx

        pygame.draw.rect(screen,cola,(acurrentx,acurrenty,4,4))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,colb,(bcurrentx,bcurrenty,4,4))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,colc,(ccurrentx,ccurrenty,4,4))
        pygame.display.flip()

        time.sleep(0.01);
        step = step + 1

    dista = sqrt((acurrentx - 240) ** 2 + (acurrenty) ** 2)
    distb = sqrt((bcurrentx - 240) ** 2 + (bcurrenty) ** 2)
    distc = sqrt((ccurrentx - 240) ** 2 + (ccurrenty) ** 2)



    if(dista<=distb and dista<=distc):
        print("a")
        movesl = movesa
    elif(distb<=dista and distb<=distc):
        print("b")
        movesl = movesb
    else:
        print("c")
        movesl = movesc

    movesa = mutateBrain(movesl)
    movesb = mutateBrain(movesa)
    movesc = mutateBrain(movesb)


    movesa = mutateBrain(movesa)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    movesb = mutateBrain(movesb)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    movesc = mutateBrain(movesc)

while 1:
    pygame.display.flip()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit() 
            exit(0)
```

Here, at the end of the first while loop, movesl always gets the same value no matter how many times I run the mutateBrain function. But it changes so there should be a problem with the random. Could somene please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not finding this very clear. What output are you expecting, and what are you getting instead?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I want the mutateBrain function to generate a dirrerent list from the inputted list. It does to some extent but if i call it again and again, it always produces the same output

Comment: You want `mutateBrain` to create a new list instead of modifying the list that you input? You'll need to do a deepcopy of the list that you pass in. Also note that lines like `movesl = movesa` make those two lists literally the same list; that doesn't make a copy. I still don't understand exactly what you're asking though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I want it to create a new list slightly modifying the given one

Comment: @Carcigenicate I have a screen. The top middle of this screen is the goal. The closest of those three dots pass their moves to the others. And then, the moves should be slightly altered by that function but it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this worked:

mutateBrain = lambda x: [[y + 0.5 - random() for y in a] for a in x]